# Spring Beans - how to wire null as a constructor arg?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following bean defined:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.me.myapp.Widget">
    <constructor-arg name="fizz" value="null"/>
    <constructor-arg name="buzz" ref="someOtherBean" />
</bean>
```

When I run my app, Spring throws a bean config exception:

```
[java] Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myBean' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0
of type [com.me.myapp.Widget]: Could not convert constructor argument value of
type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.me.myapp.Widget]: Failed to
convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
'com.me.myapp.Widget'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required
type [com.me.myapp.Widget]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I just want to create a `Widget` like I would if I wrote the following Java:

```
Widget w = new Widget(null, someOtherBean);
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use Spring's `<null>` tag:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.me.myapp.Widget">
    <constructor-arg name="fizz">
            <null />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="buzz" ref="someOtherBean" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4):

At times spring fails to inject the values in the ordered you have mentioned into a constructor. It's better if you try with explicit ordering, i.e.

```
<constructor-arg index="0" name="fizz"><null/></constructor-arg> 
<constructor-arg index="1" name="buzz"><ref bean="someOtherBean"/></constructor-arg>
```

Answer (score 0):

this was, actually, not working for me,

so what I've done is, *not* passing the object through spring,
but asking "if the object is null", and create New object and assign it to it,

it is also done once (similar to spring),
the difference is that, it is not the *best* practice, and the creation point of the object is in the flow of the class, and not in early stage.